# Setting up IntelliJ IDEA and Git

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I'd want to integrate my repo, from GitHub to IDEA 13 (Ultimate).

I set GitHub for windows. And clone my repo to local folder.
But when i try (in IDEA) use "`Check out from Version Control`", I have error message

```
Executable is not specified
```

Of cos' in setting I successfully access to my github account.

Ok, I install git, from git-scm.com, and setup path to Git executable - `git.exe`.
And now, when I click "`Check out from Version Control`", error message is:

```
Error while executing git --version. Exit code...
```

How can I troubleshoot that new error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message comes from the [`GitVersion.java#identifyVersion()` method](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/git4idea/src/git4idea/config/GitVersion.java#L139-L160) (tested in [`GitVersionTest.java`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/git4idea/tests/git4idea/tests/GitVersionTest.java)).

```
throw new ExecutionException("Errors while executing git --version. exitCode=" +
  result.getExitCode() +
  " errors: " + result.getStderr());
```

The error message can help, but you need to be sure that:

- `git.exe` is in your `PATH` environment variable,
- you have re-launched IntelliJ IDEA in order for it to inherit the updated `PATH`.

Comment: I added to PATH name: git.exe path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core\git.exe. And re-launch IDEA, but now i have third error "cannot run program "git.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified" What i do wrong?

Comment: @JazBrok simply because you need to add the *folder*, not the `git.exe` itself to the `PATH`. Plus, `git.exe` you want to reference is in `bin`: download the [**portable application (7z archive)**](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=Portable+application+for+official+Git+for+Windows&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount). Unzip it anywhere you want and add to your path `<path/to/git>\bin`